# How to add carousel for dynamic blocks from WordPress API in react native?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, api, react-native, carousel

I am implementing react native app for woocommerce WordPress website. I need to add carousel for product images, price, name which is fetched from WordPress woocommerce API. The content from API is fetched and working fine but cannot integrate carousel.

What have I done yet?

```
 render () {

     const carr = <FlatList 
                 data={this.state.data || []}
                 keyExtractor = {(x,i) =>i.toString()}
                 renderItem = {({item})=>
                 <Carousel
              ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
              renderItem={ <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => navigate("Products", { product: item })} underlayColor="transparent">
                     <View style={styles.view} >
               <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.images[0].src}} />
               <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
               <View style={styles.borderNow}></View>
               <View style={styles.cartPrice}>
                   <Text style={styles.addCart}>₹{item.price}</Text>
                   <Text style={styles.price}>

                   </Text> 
                   </View>
             </View>
                           </TouchableHighlight> 
              }
              sliderWidth={290}
              itemWidth={290}
            />
                 } />


        return (
           <View>
         {carr}
         </View>
```

I used `'react-native-snap-carousel'` this module and tried for sliding. But I get `evaluating.data.length error` . I am beginner in react.